# Play 2.1 convert Java ObjectNode to Scala Json

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

How can I convert java ObjectNode to Scala Json?

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode
import play.api.libs.json._

var objNode = JavaClass.returnObjNode()
var json = objNode.convertToScalaJson()
```